# AutoMapper's Attribute Mapping - Multiple [SourceMember]

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Attribute Mapping for my AutoMapper, mapping `Dto`s to/from their corresponding classes in an external services.
I have a case where I'm using 2 external services that are supposed to be identical in their class structure, but they're not. One of the properties has a slightly different name.

I want to declare that the source property should be either one of the options.

```
[AutoMap(typeof(ExternalService1.TransportationAsset), reverseMap = true)]
[AutoMap(typeof(ExternalService2.TransportationAsset), reverseMap = true)]
public class TransportationAssetDto {
    //In "ExternalService1" it is called "TransportType" and in "ExternalService2" it is called "TransportationType".
    [Required]
    [SourceMember("TransportationType")]
    public AssetTypeDto TransportType { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to map an instance, I'm getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, saying `cannot find member TransporationType`.

Pseudo of what I'm looking for would be: `[SourceMember("TransportType | TransportationType")]` or using a wildcard: `[SourceMember("Transport*Type")]`

Thanks

Comment: You need to switch to the fluent API.

Comment: If those `TransportationAsset` classes are defined `partial` you could add one  property each in both of them (in your own separate code) that take value from two different corresponding properties, and then you map your two properties with the same name instead of two properties with different names.